# How make multiple if conditions with regex in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, if-statement, scripting

I have 2 values, project and tag. I need check if them are empty/null and if project has only characters (except '-') and if tag has only numbers (expect '.').

User actually invert the order of them, first need be project and after tag.

I try invert the regex of `$project` and `$tag` if user wrong the order... But nothing happens, no errors and code continue.

```
if [ -z $project ] || 
   [ -z $tag ] || 
   [[ $project =~ '/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/' ]] || 
   [[ $tag =~ '/^[A-Za-z]+(\-[A-Za-z]+)*$/' ]] ; then
  echo Project or tag wrong, please try again. &&
  echo Example: file.sh project-test 1.99.2
fi
```

This code no give me errors, but also not do what I need. What I'm doing wrong here?

---- update with answer

My syntax was wrong, now it's working fine (without quotes).

```
if [[ $project =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$ ]] && 
   [[ $tag =~ ^[A-Za-z]+(\-[A-Za-z]+)*$ ]] ; then
  echo Correct
else
  echo Project or tag wrong, please try again. &&
  echo Example: file.sh project-test 1.99.2
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

only let it pass when everything all right
`grep -cP` uses perl compatible regex,  and print the number of matched lines
combined with `echo` ,count limited to 0 or 1 only
i functioned them and replace 4 "not" condition with 2 "yes" condition

```
#!/bin/bash
function check_arg() {
project=$1
tag=$2
if [ `echo $project|grep -cP '^[-a-zA-z]+$'`  -eq 1 ] &&
   [ `echo $tag|grep -cP '^[\.0-9]+$'`  -eq 1 ] ;
   then
   echo all good $project $tag
else
    echo Example : file.sh project-test 1.99.2
fi

}

check_arg project-test 99.2
check_arg 1.99.2  project-test
```

output

```
all good project-test 99.2
Example : file.sh project-test 1.99.2
```

Comment: I tried and get the error `[: -eq: unary operator expected`.

Comment: the error is telling nothing appears between ```[``` and ```-eq``` , which i should have protected with quote and counting.  could you update your post with your ```exact code piece```

Comment: you put the ending ` at the wrong place, which should go right after single quote,

Comment: I try it and get the same error, but I also find an other way that working fine, thanks you.

Comment: good luck. quotes can easily messed up and more than one way to fix